Permisson Error when writing openpy-workbook?
i try to open and save an openpyxl workbook using the following code:
import openpyxl as ox
if __name__ == '__main__':
  wb = ox.load_workbook("colSort.xlsx", rich_text=True)
  wb.save("TEST.xlsx")

But i get this Permission Error -
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr2024\ORDER\robalf\SOLcolSorting\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    wb.save("TEST.xlsx")
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 386, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 294, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 77, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 215, in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 200, in write_worksheet
    writer.write()
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 359, in write
    self.write_rows()
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 125, in write_rows
    self.write_row(xf, row, row_idx)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 147, in write_row
    write_cell(xf, self.ws, cell, cell.has_style)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\_writer.py", line 87, in etree_write_cell
    whitespace(text)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\xml\functions.py", line 85, in whitespace
    stripped = node.text.strip()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'strip'
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function _openpyxl_shutdown at 0x0000018250C27880>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 32, in _openpyxl_shutdown
    os.remove(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird: 'C:\\Users\\WRSPOL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\openpyxl.er0fcti4'

When im opening the workbook without richtext with
wb = ox.load_workbook("colSort.xlsx")

it seems to work fine.
Why is the saving not possible when i am opening the excel with richtext?

The message implies that there is already an open file named "TEST.xlsx", so the system cannot overwrite it.

But the file is not opened.
And why is this working without the rich_text=True parameter without problems?
(i tested this on 2 Windows computers Win10 and Win11 and i have the same behaviour - only on MacOs it seems to work)

The only difference is that on Windows i have Office365 and on Mac an older version - could be this the reason?

Sorry, it is not possible to guess why this error is occurring. My own experience of using Excel libraries, is that sometimes the Excel part does not close correctly and is left in a zombie state, holding the file open. On Windows you can use task manager to find any such processes.

It's referring to the Openpyxl temp file, not the file that is being saved to. To fix the problem install 'lxml', pip install lxml

With installing lxml this is really working - thanks a lot!
Can you explain a little bit what this lxml-module has to do with excel?
And why its working with richtext=True never the less?
When you provide me this as answer - i will of course accept it as solution.

Tangentially, the code you put inside if _    name__ == ‘__main__’: should be absolutely trivial. The condition is only useful when you import this code; if all the useful functionality is excluded when you import, you will never want to do that anyway. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188

An Excel file, XLSX is made up from a bunch of XML files (and a few other types) zipped and renamed with the '.xlsx' extension. Open (or unzip) an XLSX file with any unzip package and you'll see these files. Openpyxl works by editing these XML files via an API called OOXML (Office Open XML) which Microsoft provided some years back to allow manipulation of XLSX files without the Excel application.
Therefore Openpyxl uses Python XML libraries for some functions, using xml.etree as it's generally likely installed. Although another XML library may be used if installed.
Openpyxl does install 'et-xmlfile' when it is installed but that's about it, so other XML libs like 'lxml' must be installed separately.
In case of the Rich Text mode, lxml is required when saving the workbook, if it does not exist the error you saw PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '<temp file>' will result.
This may be a bug where the code fails to use xml.etree if lxml is not available or it may be written only to use lxml. I haven't looked at the code to investigate. Either way I haven't seen any notes in the Openpyxl Documentation stating lxml must be installed for rich_text= mode so it doesn't seem the author feels it's a requirement.
I would have mentioned it in the previous question but simply forgot until you raised this question.
